# VMware workstation/player does not work on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I have several Windows VMs, one of Win10 brand new VM for test, which starts, but it takes ages to get a login screen - practically speaking VMs cannot be used at all. I have used VMware for 15+ years both on Ubuntu and Windows and this isn't something trivial like too little RAM or a slow disk (it can be something else, which somebody takes for trivial, like compiling not with defaults)

I have tried VMware 16.1 / 15.5.6 / 15.5.5 and none works. I have a theoretically identical i7/Asus/16GB workstation with Windows 10 and there everything works normally (when driving the same VM from USB-3, external SATA-disk, or otherwise). I have not tried an older Ubuntu version at this time, but only this 20.04.1 with current updates. (Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 doesn't work by default with VMware, doesn't compile, but that is a different issue.)

I have tried this: a) Virtualization ON from BIOS (16.x doesn't boot without this), b) Flash BIOS to latest, c) Pro and Player versions, d) Win7 and Win 10 VMs, e) old VMs and a brand new, f) different VMware versions as mentioned above, g) running from external and internal disks

Comment: I verified this also with 18.04.1 (latest fixes). It doesn't work there any better. Does anybody know if there are specific installation instructions for VMware with versions 18.04 and 20.04? I only applied those which are needed for compiling, namely the following command:

sudo apt install gcc build-essential

I also verified, on the same computer with the same VM computer that it DOES work, as expected, with Ubuntu 16.04.1. 

Maybe there is some trick to this, which I don't know? VMware Support has not been able to help either. No actual answers from there - maybe on vacation still.

Comment: I tested this with Fedora 33. There are some specific installation prerequisite instructions for loading more packages, but anyway, they are documented. It works just fine both on Win7 and Win10 VMs. It is very strange that it doesn't work in Ubuntu.

P.S. Somebody commented through StackExchange - I cannot get those comments to appear anywhere, not in StackExchange either - can you comment here?